# love.textinput never called Love2d 11.1 on Linux

Tags: lua, love2d

Simple Question.  I am trying to get keyboard text in Love2d 11.1 with the following code in main.lua:

```
function love.load()
    text = "TextInput setting is: " .. tostring(love.keyboard.hasTextInput())
    text = text .. ". Type away! -- "
end

function love.textinput(t)
    text = text .. t
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.printf(text, 0, 0, love.graphics.getWidth())
end
```

But the code on love.textinput is never called.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Maybe you're not loading a necessary module; have a look at your `config.lua`.

Comment: No modules are disabled in conf.lua (not config.lua).  To be fully correct, I have removed all files except main.lua (with the content as listed) and the issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this.  The love2d 11.1 snap package showed the problematic behaviour.  Upgrading to the love2d 11.2 AppImage solved the problem.